# Looking for the optimal WCF quota settings

Tags: wcf, quota, maxreceivedmessagesize

I know, my question is kinda wishy washy, but what would you say are "optimal" settings for WCF quotas, e.g. MaxReceivedMessageSize etc.?

My service mostly returns small values, but sometimes the return values exceed the default quotas. There are even larger return values, which I return as streams at a second endpoint.

Now the default value for MaxReceivedMessageSize (no question, the streamed endpoint uses higher values; my question concerns buffered communication) of 65536 bytes is quite low, I think. There are tons of "tutorials" which just set this value to Int32.MaxValue, which isn't a good idea at all ;) 
Well what do you think? Which values are viable but are also safe enough not to make your service vulnerable for DoS and other stuff?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vialbe value really depends on the size of data you are expecting. If you know that sometimes you can get up to 256KB then set the value to 256KB. In case of internal service the limit can be probably set to `Int32.MaxValue` but I think it is much more about lazyness of making the assumtion about transferred data. For a public web service you will hardly set the value to `Int32.MaxValue` because anybody will be able to blow up your server.

Btw. if we are talking about data returned from the service then this decission is on the client - both quotas and `MaxReceiveMessageSize` target receiving message not sending message so if your service returns data in response to client's requests the limit will be set on the client side. For example in case of public web service you don't have all clients under your control so you must also consider how much data do you want to return.

A separate endpoint is separate configuration on both client and server sides.

Comment: It's gonna be a public web server. The service may receive up to ~512KB (so I set this value as MaxReceiveMessageSize on the service), and may also send up to ~512KB. What I don't know and what I'm uncertain about is: Is this value "dangerous"? Is it too high? If someone would send 2000 requests, the service may allocate 1GB RAM...

Comment: And do you accept 2000 concurrent requests? By default service throttling will allow only 16* processors count concurrent calls so it is your next level of defense against DoS attack. Read here about default throttling values: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/07/26/wcf-4-higher-default-throttling-settings-for-wcf-services.aspx and here about setting custom throttling http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731379.aspx

Comment: ah of course, throtteling may reduce this problem. So, 512kb may be ok, right? Thank you :)